# What is the easiest way to assign a value to words in a txt file dependent on their frequency

Tags: text, frequency, cpu-word

Either in the text, in a set of texts, or ideally in English.

It's a process I will repeat.

I'm computer illiterate, and run ubuntu and can access windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and install the "Linguist" extension for LibreOffice Writer, from http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/linguist/releases/1.5.1
2. Open LibreOffice Writer
3. Paste in your text (or open a file)
4. Go to the Linguist menu and select "Sort words on frequency"

Comment: it's a long text file and i will be repeating the process.

Comment: How about using a simple shell script? http://bashshell.net/shell-scripts/script-find-frequency-of-words-in-a-file/